# Service that adds "Over the Top" texting to landline numbers

Tags: sms, twilio, phone-call

There are plenty of companies out there offering texting to your landline without affecting voice service (ie zipwhip, heywire), but does anybody know what *they're* using? Twilio [almost offers this](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-add-the-sms-capability-to-my-toll-free-phone-number-without-porting-it-into-twilio), but it's currently in beta and only for toll free numbers. TextUs.biz has [an explanation of how they do it](http://textus.biz/faq/) in their faq, which explains that they have some sort of agreement with their SMS gateway provider that lets them get texts to a particular number routed to them, but afer a lot of googling I still can't find any resources on how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm the VP of Engineering @ HeyWire) The TextUs FAQ is spot on. SMS routing and voice routing are completely separate.  OTT text carriers like us have agreements with SMS aggregators and have to abide by industry rules and guidelines.  The agreements and rules may vary depending on whether you're doing short code, non-toll-free long code, and toll-free long code.  International and MMS are also other dimensions as well.

In general, our application stacks connect to SMS gateways, which connect to SMSCs at our aggregator partners.  Beyond that, the details of *how* everything works isn't technically complicated. Some the real special sauce comes in the details of all the agreements and partnerships required to get things up and running.  Unfortunately, those types of details fall under the umbrella of "trade secrets".  Partly due to providers not wanting to reveal too much to competitors and partly due to the agreements themselves, which prohibit disclosure of details.

Are you asking because you're trying to build something or just to try to find out some general information?

EDIT:  And I just realized I wasn't logged into my account when I posted this.  Oh well.

Comment: I'm just checking the feasibility of some options at the moment. I kinda figured the exact details would be a secret. It was just unexpected to run into this wall when everything I've wanted to do up to this point is open source or a google search away. I actually had to go to page three to research this stuff! I've never been to page three!

Comment: Sounds good.  Given the level of effort required to get a direct connect going, I definitely suggest going with an API provider.